# How to encrypt password property with fluent nhibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to create a user class on my asp.net mvc 3

But I am in doubt how to encrypt passwords when using the fluent way

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<UserGame> UserGames { get; set; }
}

public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.HiLo("1000");
        Map(x => x.Username).Unique();
        Map(x => x.Password);
        HasMany(x => x.UserGames).Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, don't encrypt passwords - hash them: http://stackoverflow.com/a/482268/54499

Comment: More or less. But also pay attention to the explanation of adding a salt to the hash to make brute force attacks more difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments suggest, hash them and use a salt, but to answer your question, check out http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/02/22/encrypting-password-or-other-strings-in-nhibernate.aspx
And then in your fluent mapping something like:

```
x.Map(x => x.Password).CustomType<EncryptedString>()
```